# A $\bmod p$ version of the Frobenius coin problem.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, finite-geometry

Let $x_1,\dots,x_d$ be $d$ integers having greatest common divisor equal to $1$. By Bézout's Lemma, there exists a least $\kappa(x_1,\dots,x_d) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that any $k \geq \kappa(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ can be written as $k = \alpha_1x_1+\dots+ \alpha_dx_d$, where $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{N}$. The Frobenius coin problem ask for estimating $\kappa_d = \max_{x_1,\dots,x_d\in\mathbb{Z}}\kappa(x_1,\dots,x_d)$.

During my research, I came up with the following variation of the Frobenius problem, which takes place in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ and which has some additional constrains on the allowed coefficients $\alpha_j$. Any comment about it is appreciated.

Does there exists $d \in \mathbb{N}$ having the following property? For every prime number $p$ and for every sequence $n_1,n_2,\dots$ in the field $F_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ we can find $k_1,\dots,k_d \subseteq F_p$ such that each $n_j$ can be written as
$$n_j = \alpha_{1,j}k_1 + \alpha_{2,j}k_2 + \dots +\alpha_{d,j}k_d,
\text{ where $0\leq \alpha_{1,j},\dots,\alpha_{d,j} \leq 3^j$.}$$

Comment: Are $i$ and $j$ actually the same variable in the bottom line?

Comment: No, I edited the question to clarify that point.

Comment: Do you include $0$ in $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: The answer feels like "no" to me. Consider a fixed $d$ and fixed valid values for $\alpha_{i,j}\ (1\le i,j\le d)$. If the $d\times d$ matrix of these $\alpha$s is invertible (mod $p$), then $k_1,\dots,k_d$ are uniquely determined by $n_1,\dots,n_d$, and thus there are at most $(3^{d+1}+1)^d$ values of $n_{d+1}$ for which those $k$s work. And the number of such matrices $\alpha_{i,j}$ is also bounded by a function of $d$. So when $p$ is large enough in terms of $d$, there will be sequences of $n$s where no $k_1,\dots,k_d$ will work for $n_1$ through $n_{d+1}$. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) This argument relied on the false hypothesis that every such $\alpha_{i,j}$ matrix is invertible (mod $p$). Can it be patched to cover the cases when that matrix is not invertible (mod $p$)? Alternatively, can we choose $p$ cleverly to avoid this issue? Certainly when $p$ is large enough, those bounded matrices are invertible (mod $p$) if and only if they are invertible over $\Bbb Q$. (since all those finitely many nonzero determinants will be nonzero modulo sufficiently large primes)

Comment: @coffeemath yes

Comment: @GregMartin I get your point, I thought something similar while working in this question, but I couldn't find a concrete example where it fails. Finding such example would be very useful for me as using either a positive or negative answer to this question I can solve my original problem.